# Responsive Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm doing a very basic website for my football team and I have a Jumbotron background image which is resizing in different screen sizes - working perfectly, however I've got text outside the Jumbotron in a small screen size (less than 576px) which isn't staying close to the background image.

The text just stays in the same place as the screen is made smaller and I want it to follow the background image. Any ideas....here's the code:

```css
html {
  background-color: ffff00;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  font-family: 'nunito' !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper {
  background-color: 0000ff;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0% auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: 0000ff;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.navbar {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
}

.navbarcenter {
  margin: auto;
}

nav .navbar-nav li {
  justify-content: space-between !important;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

nav .navbar-nav li a {
  color: ffff00 !important;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: ffff00 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

html body .container .jumbotron {
  min-width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  background-image: url(https://imgur.com/wzo1pmU.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: 0000ff;
}

.responsive {
  color: 0000ff;
}

.responsive-small {
  color: 0000ff;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

@media(max-width:568px) {
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  p {
    color: transparent;
  }
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    background-image: url(https://imgur.com/QYDb3BF.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 45%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  .responsive {
    color: ffff00;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0%;
  }
  .responsive-small {
    color: ffff00;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    max-height: 55%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }
  p.lead {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    padding-bottom: 1.7%;
  }
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    min-width: 60%;
    max-height: 65%;
  }
  p.lead {
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    min-width;
    60%;
    min-height: 80%;
  }
  .container .jumbotron p.lead {
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  p.lead {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ansty FC Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"> <!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>
        <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-inline-block d-lg-none d-inline-block" href="#">Ansty FC</a>
        <div class="w-100 text-right">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item nav-active">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Committee</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Kit</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron mx-auto col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
        <p class="lead">Ansty Sports and Social FC, Setting the Mid Sussex League alight with flair, passion and glory. </p>
        <p>Divisions 1, and 4 South in the Mid Sussex Football League.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="responsive">Ansty Sports and Social FC, Setting the Mid Sussex League alight with flair, passion and glory. </p>
    <p class="responsive-small">Divisions 1, and 4 South in the Mid Sussex Football League.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at commented code in CSS part

```css
html {
  background-color: ffff00;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  font-family: 'nunito' !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper {
  background-color: 0000ff;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0% auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: 0000ff;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.navbar {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
}

.navbarcenter {
  margin: auto;
}

nav .navbar-nav li {
  justify-content: space-between !important;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

nav .navbar-nav li a {
  color: ffff00 !important;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: ffff00 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

html body .container .jumbotron {
  min-width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  background-image: url(https://imgur.com/wzo1pmU.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: 0000ff;
}

.responsive {
  color: 0000ff;
}

.responsive-small {
  color: 0000ff;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

@media(max-width:568px) {
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    background-image: url(https://imgur.com/QYDb3BF.jpg);
    height: 45%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  .responsive {
    color: ffff00;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0%;
  }
  .responsive-small {
    color: ffff00;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    max-height: 55%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }
  p.lead {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    padding-bottom: 1.7%;
  }
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    min-width: 60%;
    max-height: 65%;
  }
  p.lead {
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html body .container .jumbotron {
    min-width;
    60%;
    min-height: 80%;
  }
  .container .jumbotron p.lead {
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  p.lead {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}

/* Drop this rules from your code to saw the same efect for small screens */
/* 
   @media(max-width:568px) {
     p { // to show text
       color: transparent;
     }
     html body .container .jumbotron {
       background-size: contain; // to apply styles the same as for other resolutions
     } 
   }
*/
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ansty FC Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"> <!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>
        <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-inline-block d-lg-none d-inline-block" href="#">Ansty FC</a>
        <div class="w-100 text-right">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item nav-active">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Committee</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Kit</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link m-2 menu-item">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron mx-auto col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
        <p class="lead">Ansty Sports and Social FC, Setting the Mid Sussex League alight with flair, passion and glory. </p>
        <p>Divisions 1, and 4 South in the Mid Sussex Football League.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="responsive">Ansty Sports and Social FC, Setting the Mid Sussex League alight with flair, passion and glory. </p>
    <p class="responsive-small">Divisions 1, and 4 South in the Mid Sussex Football League.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```